# UILongPressGestures conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have a container view which has two UILongPressGestureRecognizers on it (well not only those two, but other gestures are acting ok). One is to recognize one finger, the other is for two. When i try to fire gesture for one finger, it will not fire it's target method until finger is lift off. The second one for two fingers is working as expected, firing selector action after short period of time. When i disable gesture for two finger press, the one finger press gets back to normal. How gestures are initialized, first is one finger gesture, initialized inside vc setup.

```
 - (void) setupGestures
{
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.longGestureRecognizer];
}

- (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longGestureRecognizer
{
    if (!_longGestureRecognizer) {
        _longGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAction:)];
        [_longGestureRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:1];
    }
    return _longGestureRecognizer;
}
```

The second one is initalized a bit later, but not from host VC, but inside view which is added to it

```
//Called in host
rullerView = [[RullerView alloc] initWithContent:self.contentView viewController:self];
```

and in init of view:

```
//This is called from within previous call initWithContent:ciewController:
- (void)setupGestures
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *rullerGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rullerTapAction:)];
    [rullerGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    //view here is a content view passed into init, basically the same one
    //to which first recognizer is added, however selector action is contained 
    //in this view, and this view is target for this recognizer
    [view addGestureRecognizer:rullerGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Could this be a problem?? Already tried

```
[gesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:otherGesture];
```

and delegate method of view which recognizers are added to:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I just did a quick test - no problems, even without the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method (although, they are in the same VC class). Maybe try it on a fresh VC, with no other code or objects? Or, show a little more detail on how you are initializing them from different classes?

Comment: @DonMag look at my edit

Comment: Hmmm... must be something else going on. Trying to follow your description - I set up a test project and have no troubles. I put it up as a GitHub repo if you want to take a look and see if there is something obviously different: https://github.com/DonMag/LongPressTesting